# How to get the weight of an eigenstate inside the state of the system without knowing the state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, eigenvalue, observables

Let us suppose we have a system in a state $\Psi$, with:

$\Psi = \sum_m c_m \psi_m$

Let us further suppose that we don't know what $\Psi$ or the $c_m$ are, but that we know what the $\psi_m$ are since we managed to retrieve them from a time-independent SE. How does one then obtain the coefficients $c_m$? (i.e. how does one come to know "how much" of any state of the basis is inside the state of the specific system they are considering?).

Comment: What's the context here? How did you define the $c_m$? What do you mean by us "not knowing $\Psi$"? Any proof that $\Psi$ can be written as a linear combination of the $\psi_m$ should give an explicit formula for the $c_m$ (and more generally this is something you should be able to guess from finite-dimensional linear algebra).

Comment: If you just know that the state vector is *any* linear (possible infinite) linear combination, then this is an impossible task. Even in finite dimensions there are uncountably many different vectors which are linear combinations of a (finite) set of vectors. Suppose, for example, that the (normalized) vector of interest $v$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$. Then you can write $v=c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2$. Now every tuple of complex numbers $(c_1,c_2)$ with $|c_1|^2+ |c_2|^2 = 1$ gives a different vector and there are uncountably many of such tuples.

Comment: Note that if we don't know $\Psi$, the question is ill-posed. It's akin to asking how we can express a vector $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^2$ in component form $x\hat{\mathbf{i}}+y\hat{\mathbf{j}}$ if we don't know what $\mathbf{v}$, $x$, and $y$ are.

Comment: I agree with all of you! The reason for my question is that I thought there was some more information that I should have known from somewhere else, and I hoped you could tell me where from. But the problem really is as stated: suppose you want to know the state of any system ($\Psi$ in my question) and suppose furthermore you know the exact expression of, for example, the Hamiltonian of the system. Then, solving the eigenvalue problem gives you all of the eigenvalues. But how do I know how probable each of those eigenvalues is?

Comment: After all, the only thing I have to know the state of the system is the SE. If by solving that I only get the expansion on the basis and not the coefficients of that expansion, how can I know which is the exact state of the system I'm considering?

Comment: The SE doesn't actually tell you very much about what the possible states your system could be in, since with finite $V(x)$ you can expand pretty much any state you want in the eigenbasis of $H$, which is complete. Instead, it governs how these states evolve with time. You can think of solving the TISE as something that gives you a good basis to use - it doesn't tell you what vector you can have, just gives you a nice basis to express it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, I understand your question as follows: by solving the time-independent Schrödinger equation, we only find the eigenstates $|\psi_m\rangle$ of the Hamiltonian. How do we know what the state of the system is?

The answer is that we cannot get the state of the system from the Schrödinger equation. It depends on the initial conditions: you prepare the system in some state $|\Psi_0\rangle$ and the state at a later time $|\Psi_t\rangle$ depends on what the initial state was. In fact, if
$$ |\Psi_0\rangle = \sum_m c_m |\psi_m\rangle \text{, then} $$
$$ |\Psi_t\rangle = \sum_m c_m \mathrm e^{-\mathrm i E_m t / \hbar}\, |\psi_m\rangle , $$
i.e. the absolute value of the coefficients in this expansion does not change.

Note that the situation changes if the system is not *closed*, that is, if it thermalizes due to interaction with some kind of environment. In that case, the system will typically evolve into a thermal equilibrium state described by the density matrix $\rho = Z^{-1}\, \mathrm e^{-\beta H}$, where $Z$ is the partition function, $\beta$ the inverse temperature and $H$ the Hamiltonian. (I am adding this note because this might be the reason for your intuition, which seems to be that the state of the system is determined by the system and not the initial conditions.)